# What was a For loop? Why isn't it needed in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, s

In [the R FAQ's section about comparing S and R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Others), we find the following:

> In R, For() loops are not necessary and hence not supported.

What was a `For()` loop and why does R not need it?

Comment: It appears to have been a method of speeding up the normal `for` loop. I suspect that it has been incorporated into the `for` loop in R so it is unnecessary.

Comment: @dcarlson Do you have a source for that?

Comment: I was able to find a copy of [S-PLUS: Programmer’s Guide online](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall99/sta240/PGUIDE.PDF). Check pages 647-648  on `For` loops. The S-Plus manual discourages using 'for` loops and encourages `apply` family approaches, but R seems to have optimized `for` loops to the point that those recommendations are now moot.

Comment: @dcarlson That looks good enough to turn in to an answer. Have at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a copy of [S-PLUS: Programmer’s Guide](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall99/sta240/PGUIDE.PDF) online. Pages 647-648 contrast `for` and `For` loops. The S-Plus manual generally discourages using `for` loops (pp. 120, 639-641) and encourages `apply` family approaches, but R has optimized `for` loops to the point that those recommendations are now moot and the "optimized" `For` loop is no longer necessary.